# Returns a copy of the list with the first number of items reversed

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = ['e', 'd', 'u', 'd']
list2 = ['m', 'o', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd']

def reverse(list, number):
    number = (my_list[0])
    for i in my_list:
        my_list = str(my_list[number]) + str(i)
    return my_list
```

Output should be:

```
[d,u,d,e]
[b,o,m,b,e,d]
```

Comment: Don't write the question in the topic and no question content in the body, it's like reading one of those annoying emails from that annoying colleague that writes everything in the subject field but nothing in the body.

Comment: And if you reverse list2, you won't get "bombed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = ['e', 'd', 'u', 'd']
>>> list2 = ['m', 'o', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd']
>>> def reverse(L, num):
...     return L[:num][::-1] + L[num:]
... 
>>> reverse(list1, 4)
['d', 'u', 'd', 'e']
>>> reverse(list2, 3)
['b', 'o', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

Using only loops:

```
>>> list1 = ['e', 'd', 'u', 'd']
>>> list2 = ['m', 'o', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd']
>>> def reverse(L, num):
...     new_list=[]
...     for i in reversed(range(num)):
...          new_list+=L[i]
...     for i in range(num, len(L)):
...          new_list+=L[i]
...     return new_list
... 
>>> reverse(list1, 4)
['d', 'u', 'd', 'e']
>>> reverse(list2, 3)
['b', 'o', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
>>> def reverse(l,num):
    return [l[n] for n in range(num-1,-1,-1)] + l[num:]

>>> list1 = ['e', 'd', 'u', 'd']
>>> list2 = ['m', 'o', 'b', 'b', 'e', 'd']
>>> reverse(list1,4)
['d', 'u', 'd', 'e']
>>> reverse(list2,3)
['b', 'o', 'm', 'b', 'e', 'd']
```